# replicate a dataframe for a second subject ID

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  TIME AMT A1 A2  DV
 1  0   100 100 0   NA
 1  1   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  2   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  3   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  4   100 NA  NA  NA
 1  5   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  6   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  6   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  7   0   NA  NA  NA
```

Is there a way in R that I can replicate it but change ID into ID =2. The result should look like this:

```
ID  TIME AMT A1 A2  DV
 1  0   100 100 0   NA
 1  1   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  2   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  3   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  4   100 NA  NA  NA
 1  5   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  6   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  6   0   NA  NA  NA
 1  7   0   NA  NA  NA
 2  0   100 100 0   NA
 2  1   0   NA  NA  NA
 2  2   0   NA  NA  NA
 2  3   0   NA  NA  NA
 2  4   100 NA  NA  NA
 2  5   0   NA  NA  NA
 2  6   0   NA  NA  NA
 2  6   0   NA  NA  NA
 2  7   0   NA  NA  NA
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing + `transform`:

```
transform(dat[rep(rownames(dat),2),], ID = rep(1:2,each=nrow(dat) ))
```

Or as a function:

```
rep.and.count <- function(x,n) {
  transform(x[rep(rownames(x),n),], ID = rep(seq_len(n),each=nrow(x) ))
}
rep.and.count(dat,2)
```

It's a lot faster even with pretty small data.

```
ids <- 1:15000
system.time({do.call(rbind, lapply(ids, function(id) {
  new.dat <- dat
  new.dat$ID <- id
  return(new.dat)
}))})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.61    0.03    8.78

system.time(rep.and.count(dat,15000))

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.13    0.00    0.13
```

Comment: Thank you. But the function doesn't give a new ID for relpicated data. I would like the ID to be updated to ID=2

Comment: is there a way to give an updated ID? It is much faster to use as you mentioned. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry you are right. it is adding it as a new column. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use split-apply-combine to build a new data frame with each desired id and then combine them using `rbind`:

```
ids <- c(1, 2)
do.call(rbind, lapply(ids, function(id) {
  new.dat <- dat
  new.dat$ID <- id
  return(new.dat)
}))
#    ID TIME AMT  A1 A2 DV
# 1   1    0 100 100  0 NA
# 2   1    1   0  NA NA NA
# 3   1    2   0  NA NA NA
# 4   1    3   0  NA NA NA
# 5   1    4 100  NA NA NA
# 6   1    5   0  NA NA NA
# 7   1    6   0  NA NA NA
# 8   1    6   0  NA NA NA
# 9   1    7   0  NA NA NA
# 10  2    0 100 100  0 NA
# 11  2    1   0  NA NA NA
# 12  2    2   0  NA NA NA
# 13  2    3   0  NA NA NA
# 14  2    4 100  NA NA NA
# 15  2    5   0  NA NA NA
# 16  2    6   0  NA NA NA
# 17  2    6   0  NA NA NA
# 18  2    7   0  NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dfout = ddf
for(i in 2:5) {ddf[,1]=i; dfout = rbind(dfout, ddf)}
dfout
   ID TIME AMT  A1 A2 DV
1   1    0 100 100  0 NA
2   1    1   0  NA NA NA
3   1    2   0  NA NA NA
4   1    3   0  NA NA NA
5   1    4 100  NA NA NA
6   1    5   0  NA NA NA
7   1    6   0  NA NA NA
8   1    6   0  NA NA NA
9   1    7   0  NA NA NA
10  2    0 100 100  0 NA
11  2    1   0  NA NA NA
12  2    2   0  NA NA NA
13  2    3   0  NA NA NA
14  2    4 100  NA NA NA
15  2    5   0  NA NA NA
16  2    6   0  NA NA NA
17  2    6   0  NA NA NA
18  2    7   0  NA NA NA
19  3    0 100 100  0 NA
20  3    1   0  NA NA NA
21  3    2   0  NA NA NA
22  3    3   0  NA NA NA
23  3    4 100  NA NA NA
24  3    5   0  NA NA NA
25  3    6   0  NA NA NA
26  3    6   0  NA NA NA
27  3    7   0  NA NA NA
28  4    0 100 100  0 NA
29  4    1   0  NA NA NA
30  4    2   0  NA NA NA
31  4    3   0  NA NA NA
32  4    4 100  NA NA NA
33  4    5   0  NA NA NA
34  4    6   0  NA NA NA
35  4    6   0  NA NA NA
36  4    7   0  NA NA NA
37  5    0 100 100  0 NA
38  5    1   0  NA NA NA
39  5    2   0  NA NA NA
40  5    3   0  NA NA NA
41  5    4 100  NA NA NA
42  5    5   0  NA NA NA
43  5    6   0  NA NA NA
44  5    6   0  NA NA NA
45  5    7   0  NA NA NA
```